# Differential equation: finding particular solution when the RHS is in form A/t

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Knowing that $$t^2y'' + 3ty' - 3y = 16t$$ for the homogeneous equation has a general solution $$y= c_1t + c_2t^{-3}$$
What is the particular solution?

If I divide $t^2$ across the board, I will obtain the RHS in form of $16/t$.

How do you 'guess' the form of $y_p$ for this type of form?

Comment: The general solution isn't $y=c_1t+c_2t^{-3}$. It seems like it is the solution to the associated homogeneous equation, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Use the method of [Variation of parameters](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/second/variation/variation.html). You have here $$u'_1=\frac{-y_2\times(16/t) }{y_1y'_2-y'_1y_2}, u'_2=\frac{y_1\times(16/t) }{y_1y'_2-y'_1y_2},~~~~~t\neq0, y_1=t, y_2=t^{-3}$$ and that $y_p=y_1u_1+y_2u_2$.

Comment: Thanks Amzoti. I have not been on a proper mood these days. My presented Semigroup and its damned elements move on my head day and night. It seems that they need a better king than me. Poor me.

Comment: How to know when I need to apply the method of variation of parameter?

Comment: @40Plot: It is when you encounter a non homogenous linear equation of higher order.

Comment: @BabakS.: I am sure you will make progress and you figure out a way! I wish you the best in these trying times, which I am also going through! Regards

Comment: Nice work, Babak! Do not fret; you will find your way and conquer the semigroup and its elements!

Answer (score 4):

We will use variation of parameters. So suppose $y_p=u_1y_1+u_2y_2$, where $y_1=t$ and $y_2=t^{-3}$. Then we get the equation

$$ \begin{pmatrix}y_1 & y_2 \\ 
y'_1 & y'_2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} u_1' \\ u_2' \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 16/t \end{pmatrix}.$$

Inverting the matrix, we get
$$\begin{pmatrix} u_1' \\ u_2' \end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'}\begin{pmatrix}y_2' & -y_2 \\ -y_1' & y_1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 16/t\end{pmatrix}$$
The rest is easily solved by integration.